# Добавление значений в массив в php

Tags: php

```
$j="ghghghg";
function processMessage($update) {
    if($update["result"]["action"] == "sayHello"){
        sendMessage(array(
            "source" => $update["result"]["source"],
            "speech" => $j,
            "displayText" => $j,
            "contextOut" => array()
        ));
    }
}

function sendMessage($parameters) {
    echo json_encode($parameters);
}

$update_response = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update_response, true);
if (isset($update["result"]["action"])) {
    processMessage($update);
}
```

Добрый день. У меня возникла проблем в невозможности передать значение в массив , а конкретно в "speech" и "displayText". Спасибо.

Comment: Прочитайте про области видимости. Переменной `$j` просто не существует внутри вашей функции

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите использовать глобальную переменную внутри функции -

```
$j="ghghghg";

function processMessage($update) {
    global $j;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал так делать. Жуткий антипаттерн. Лучше через аргумент функции

Comment: Как так делать вы бы не рекомендовали?

Comment: Не рекомендуется использовать `global`, небезопасная конструкция языка, прочитайте про `Dependency injection`. Да и вообще лучше через аргументы передавать. В `global` одни минусы и не читабельно в принципе, да и вообще не оправданно его использование.

Comment: Ну не рекомендуйте автору. Автор спрашивает как использовать глобальную переменную внутри функции. Я отвечаю на вопрос как использовать глобальную переменную внутри функции.

Comment: Автор просто не понимает, что он делает в принципе. А вы советуете не понимая, что советуете, к тому-же "изжиток-всего".

Comment: Я не вижу никаких оснований предполагать, что автор не понимает того, что он делает. Он мог всю жизнь на С++ писать допустим и просто быть не в курсе, что для того, что бы использовать глобальную переменную внутри функции ее нужно объявлять как глобальную внутри функции. Это раз. Два - нет ничего плохого в использовании глобальных переменных в программе из пяти функций.